# Binding list of paragraphs to RichTextBlock

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp, richtextblock

Right now, I have the data I need binding to a `RichTextBlock`, but I'm unable to format it, since I'm just using one long string bound to the `run` on a paragraph setup in my `RichTextBlock`. Obviously, this isn't ideal. I would like to be able to change font sizes or font weights for some words, but can't see of a way to do that with my current method.

```
<RichTextBlock TextAlignment="Justify" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Name="richTB">
    <Paragraph>
        <Run Text="{Binding}" />
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBlock>
```

I know I can create a `RichTextBlock` in my code behind, and add paragraphs manually to that, but how would I bind it? Since it's in my `page.resources`?

Comment: What is the binding source? I mean, if it is a plain text, then how do you plan to get formatting info (this line is bold, this line is italic, etc.)? If it is a RTF document, then you'll need to perform manual conversion from RTF to the XAML's flow document (e.g., by attaching a binding converter to `RichTextBlock.Blocks` property).

Comment: Currently, it's just one really long string. But I can change it to a bunch of `paragraph`'s pretty easily that can be formatted, I just don't know how I would bind that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't really bind it if you want to do custom formatting on the string. XAML builds those controls, and you can't really generate those controls through a binding the way you want.

What you could do is hook up an `OnLoad` event handler for your control, and inject whatever paragraph/run controls via C#.

Comment: It would have to be bound. I can't inject the paragraphs in since it's a resource control. Being repeated up to 10 times on the page.

Comment: Yeah there aren't a lot of options. The best way might be to hook up the same loaded event for each RichTextBox. No code duplication that way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are {binding} the source and hence inside the Code, you can take help from this code:

```
Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
            para.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = sample, FontSize = 15 });            
            rtb.Blocks.Add(para);
```

where rtb is a richtextblock.